# Deezer SDK for iOS arm64 library

Tags: ios, deezer, arm64

Apple will required application to support both 32 and 64 bits architecture by February 2015.
Deezer SDK for iOS doesn't include arm64 library.

Will may application be rejected by Apple on February 2015?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see Deezer iOS SDK version 0.9.0 (just passed from beta to official) is 64 bit.

Source: executed `lipo -info libDeezer.a` 
and obtained

```
Architectures in the fat file: libDeezer.a are: armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64 arm64
```